# How can I dynamically use string.replace?

Tags: javascript, string

```
wordsArray = ['guy', 'like', 'sweet', 'potatoes']; //so on and so forth
string = "I am a **NOUN** and I **VERB** **ADJECTIVE** **NOUN**.";
DELIMITER = "**";

for (var i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++)
{
    string.replace(DELIMITER, wordsArray[i]);
}
```

Hi, this is a simplified version of my code. I'm creating a mad lib, and the length of wordsArray will always be equal to the number of fill in the blanks. The problem with my current code is that in the for loop, it will replace every `**`. The thing is, I want to replace the entire thing, like `**NOUN**`, not just `**`. But since whatever is in between `** **` won't always be the same, string.replace() won't exactly work. Can Anyone suggest me an edit that could replace all the part of speeches but still eventually return string as a, well, block of proper text?

Comment: You’d do this with a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `string.match` by catching all those `**<STRINGS>**` first:

```js
var wordsArray = ['guy', 'like', 'sweet', 'potatoes'];
var string = "I am a **NOUN** and I **VERB-** **ADJECTIVE** **NOUN**.";
var DELIMITER = "**";

var newString = string; // copy the string
var stringArray = string.match(/(\*\*[A-Za-z-]+\*\*)/g); // array of all **<STRINGS>**

for (var i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
  newString = newString.replace(stringArray[i], wordsArray[i]);
}

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: Oh that's really helpful! One more question though. Sometimes the part of speech may have -, like VERB-ENDING-IN-ING. What would I include in the match parameters to include that -?

Comment: @idontknowanygoodusernames do you mean something like `**VERB-**` ? In that case you will have to update the regex used in `.match()`. See my updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your array to the replacer and call replace on your string once, I think it is much simpler:

```
"I am a **NOUN** and I **VERB** **ADJECTIVE** **NOUN**.".replace(/(\*\*\w+\*\*)/gi,(function(){
    this._currentIndex = this._currentIndex || 0;
    return this[this._currentIndex++];
}).bind(['guy', 'like', 'sweet', 'potatoes']));

//"I am a guy and I like sweet potatoes."
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce:

```
const string = "I am a **NOUN** and I **VERB** **ADJECTIVE** **NOUN**.";
const newString = ['guy', 'like', 'sweet', 'potatoes'].reduce(
  (theString, replacement) => theString.replace(/\*{2}\w+\*{2}/, replacement),
  string
)
```